# Verificando se um numero é primo

Tags: javascript, lógica

Quero rodar um for de 1 até 5 e em seguida quero saber se algum dos numeros do for é primo.

```
for(j = 1 ; j<= 10; j++){ //Percorres os numeros a serem testados
    for(i = 1;i <= j; i++){ // Listo Todos os divisores
      var numeroDivisores = 0;
    if(j % i == 0){
      numeroDivisores++ //Adiciona os divisores daquele numero
    }
  }                      
} if (numeroDivisores == 2){// vou pegar cada divisor e dividir por numero primo
    console.log("Primo, somente 2x divisores")
}else{
    console.log("Infelizmente não é primo")
  }
```

Comment: Se queria fazer o `for` de 1 a 5, por que fez `j <= 10`? De qualquer forma, se pesquisar no site, encontrará [vários algoritmos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+primo) para verificar se um número é primo.

Comment: @hkotsubo Foi um erro de atenção ali, perdão.

Answer (score 4):

Haviam muitos erros lógicos então achei mais mais fácil refatorar o seu código do que fazer correções pontuais.

```js
var numeroDivisores;
//É comum utilizar os iteradores em ordem alfabética ordenando dos pelo grau de aninhamento
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

  numeroDivisores = 0; // A cada novo número a ser verificado o número de divisores é zerado.

  //Simplificando o caso de teste de divisibilidade.
  for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    if (i % j == 0) numeroDivisores++;

  //Depois de testada a divisibilidade cada número é categorizado conforme o número de divisores.
  console.log((numeroDivisores === 2) ? `Primo ${i}, somente 2x divisores` : `Infelizmente ${i} não é primo`);

}
```